# how to apply generics and access methods of diff class?

Tags: java

I have these two classes

class 1 :

```
public class MyClass1
{
    public void myClass1Print()
    {
        System.out.println("in myClass1Print");
    }
}
```

class 2 :

```
public class MyClass2
{
    public void myClass1Print()
    {
        System.out.println("in myClass1Print");
    }
}
```

How can I create a generic method in class 3 so that the method takes the parameters as generic.

class 3 :

```
public class MyClass3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyClass3 obj3 = new MyClass3();
        MyClass1 obj1 = new MyClass1();
        MyClass2 obj2 = new MyClass2();
        obj3.methodMyClass3(obj1, obj2);
    }

    public <T> void methodMyClass3(T exp,T act)
    {
        System.out.println("obj1===>>>"+exp.myClass1Print());// compilation error
        System.out.println("obj2===>>>"+act.myClass2Print());// compilation error
    }

}
```

since the arguments exp and act are not considered as Objects of MyClass1 , MyCLass2 
thus Compilatin error is

```
The method myClass1Print() is undefined for the type T
The method myClass2Print() is undefined for the type T
```

Comment: If you have compilation errors you should post that too.

Comment: You have a misunderstanding of how generics work. There's no way for the compiler to know, inside `methodMyClass3`, that `exp` and `act` are of type `MyClassXyz`. Consider using generic bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an **Interface**

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface GenenericPrint {
    void myClassPrint();
}

public class MyClass1 implements GenenericPrint {
    @Override
    public void myClassPrint(){
        System.out.println("print something from Class1");
    }
}

public class MyClass2 implements GenenericPrint {
    @Override
    public void myClassPrint(){
        System.out.println("print something from Class2");
    }
}

public class MyClass3{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyClass3 obj3 = new MyClass3();
        GenenericPrint obj1 = new MyClass1();
        GenenericPrint obj2 = new MyClass2();

        obj3.methodMyClass3(obj1, obj2);
    }

    public void methodMyClass3(GenenericPrint exp,GenenericPrint act){
        System.out.println("obj1===>>>"+exp.myClassPrint());// no compilation error
        System.out.println("obj2===>>>"+act.myClassPrint());// no compilation error
    }
}
```